# Is it possible to use avy to jump to known positions in a buffer?

Tags: motion, avy

I want to use avy to jump to fields in a bibtex entry. I have only found a way to use a regex to specify jump places in avy so far. I don't want to just build a regex to match the fields in an entry, because it would also match fields in another entry, and I want to limit the jump candidates to the entry. Is this doable?

Comment: I did find a way to limit the scope of targets; you can specify a beginning and end in (avy--generic-jump regex nil avy-style beg end). So in this case, I can construct a regex on the fields and use that to jump to a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question... Here is a way to get an avy style jump tree to positions 1, 4 or 12. You could use any list of positions you want, e.g. calculated from some function.

```
(avy-with my-jumper (avy--process '(1 4 12) (avy--style-fn avy-style)))
```